# How to integrate native runtime library with dlopen on NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

For my native c++ project I've to set up a runtime loading of a precompiled shared library, which could be changed by client side on start up using configurations. What is the proper way of calling dlopen on android?  No matter what I do, dlopen can never open any shared library, if I not define this library as precompiled library in my Android.mk file like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := bar
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bar/bar.cpp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/bar
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := native_activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bar

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module, android/native_app_glue)
```

In my native activity main class I try to load the library with:

```
void* lib = dlopen("/system/lib/armeabi-v7a/libbar.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (lib == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not dlopen(\"libbar.so\"): %s\n",
    dlerror());
    exit(1);
}else{
    LOGI("Library successfully loaded!");

    if (dlsym(lib, "bar") == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Symbol 'bar' is missing from shared library!!\n");        
    }else{
        LOGI("Library symbol found!"); 
    }

    int x = bar(25);
    LOGI("Bar return value: %i", x);
}
```

The disadventage of this implementation is that is not really a runtime loading, because I've to load this library also on JNI startup using JAVA mechanisms.

If I remove the bar library precompile defintions from Android.mk, disable JNI loading on startup and add a copy of the precompiled library to the systems/lib folder where it should be (same place where it is stored using precompile definitions), the loading of the library fails.  I've checked the apk package it contains my manually copied library at lib folder as expected.

Why this will not work?  Is it possible to perform a strict native runtime library loading of an external precompiled library? And what is the best way to ensure that my library is added to the apk package?

Comment: Unless you are working with rooted device, or building the platform from scratch, you cannot deploy your libraries to `/system/lib`. At any rate, you are probably mixing the way APK is organized (with `/libs/armeabi-v7a`, `/libs/x86`, **etc** folders of shared libraries) and the way Android installs the apps, extracting the libraries that match the device ABI to `/data/data/<your.package>/lib` directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best strategy on Android is to load all native libraries from Java, even if you choose which libraries to load, by some runtime rules. You can use **dlsym(0, ...)** then to access exported functions there.

APK builder will pick up all **.so** files it finds in `libs/armeabi-v7a` and the installer will unpack them into `/data/data/<your.package>/lib` directory.

Comment: My problem is, that the native application I've to port to android uses a library manager to load dependencies on runtime. By this reason JAVA is not an option ...

Comment: Java is always an option. You probably have to make adaptations to the original library manager to fit the Android security and distribution model. One of the options is to implement part of this manager as a call back to Java function that will simply call System.LoadLibrary().

Comment: The main problem with implementing an equivalent of `System.LoadLibrary()` in C, is that the location `/data/data/<your.package>/lib` is a non-documented implementation detail, which may change on any future release of the OS or due to some tweaking by one of the OEMs.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I will check this out. Meanwhile I solved the problem, regarding your informations about library location. If I regard "/data/data/<your.package>/lib" as library search path, I could successfully use dlopen to load the external precompiled library.

Comment: @Alex Cohn :  how to do this if you don't yet know what <your.package> is ? (I am shipping a dynamic library, that can be used by multiple different software)

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: if your dynamic library must be loaded by multiple different softwares, then finding the correct path for **dlopen()** is not your problem, but theirs. They may choose to use the recent option of NDK, called *[crazy linker](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/ndk/sources/android/crazy_linker/README.TXT)*, which essentially adds the app native library directory to the load path. If your **.so** must use **dlopen()** to load some other pieces, then you can resolve the path to your binary via `/proc`, and derive from that the path to other libs.

Comment: I am in the second case (my .so loads other .so's) and I fixed it the way you said !