# Dynamically loading C++ library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to load C++ library dynamically in to the Android project. Is there any other method of loading/linking library dynamically other than System.LoadLibrary() function call ?

Are there any good tools available to debug whether the Activity classes invoke the C++ library ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use a different method?  In terms of detecting if library functions are invoked, logging from the native side would work, or if you can't modify the library, make a wrapping library and put the logging in that instead.

Comment: I have a legacy project that uses a C++ library. But I could not find the System.loadLibrary() function call in the java classes. So I want to know is there a different method to load/link C++ library dynamically.

Comment: I think dlopen is what you are looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719149/how-to-integrate-native-runtime-library-with-dlopen-on-ndk

Answer (score 1):

`dlopen()` and related functions in `dlfcn.h` allow you to dynamically load libraries from within the NDK. http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/bionic/libc/include/dlfcn.h