# Android Q path to dynamic libraries (.so) not found on runtime

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-10.0

I have made an update on Android Studio including Gradle (5.4.1 > 5.6.4). Since the update, I can not find my dynamic libraries anymore. Formerly, I have checked the folder `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir` (JNI to C++ via interface) and there I found all my libraries. Since the update, there are not copied to this place anymore. If I try to open the files with `dlopen("name_of_lib.so", RTLD_NOW)` it works. So they are there but not in the folder.

Do you have an advice where the libraries are stored or how to get the path to the folder?

Best, Tobias.

Comment: Perhaps the default for `extractNativeLibs` has changed to `false`. That is in fact the case if you also upgraded the Android plugin to 3.6.0 or later.

Comment: See the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551499/1524450) for possible solutions.

Comment: extractNativeLibs was the solution to this problem. I have checked the related answer and it is exactly my question. But changing android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs to false doesn't help in my case. Strange. I need to find a more general solution in the future but it works now. Thx.