# Missing .so file lib when building in App Bundle

Tags: java, android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, .so

I'm trying to release an app on the Playstore that includes .so lib files. When I try to debug it, the app works fine. But when I try to release it  and upload it on the PlayStore via .aab and install it, my app can't find the .so file that I put in the Jnilibs folder. It says

> .so file Not Found

I tried many solutions
(ndk, abifilters, split, etc.)
but nothing worked. I'm using Android Studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 version.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I've gone in details to explain why that happens and how to fix it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551499/4265103

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yess you are right I will mark this As an Accepted Answer

Comment: Could you please explain ```useLegacyPackaging = true```, what does it do?

Comment: Is it still relevant in 2022?

Comment: @Sujith It is equivalent to setting [android:extractNativeLibs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs)="true" in the APK version.

Comment: @Sujith I'm not sure if this problem has been completely resolved. Check [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127691101](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127691101)

Comment: this is an answer! the docs say just add useLegacyPackaging in your build.gradle. yea, great! thx @BlueOcean, may your water always be clear!

Comment: Hi @BlueOcean et al, Thanks for your answers and comments. I am trying this method and I am wondering if there is any way to confirm the generated apk file from updated bundle with "useLegacyPackaging = true" before I upload the bundle file to developer console. I generated the bundle files and used "bundletool build-apks ..." command to generate apks files but I could not see the difference in apk files/structure between the bundle files with "useLegacyPackaging = true" and the bundle without "useLegacyPackaging = true". Thanks,

Comment: @LocHuynh If you use **"useLegacyPackaging = true"** the generated apk will include the **compressed .so libraries**. Otherwise the generated apk will contain **uncompressed .so libraries**. After creating the apk file using bundletool, compare the apk files: **unzip -lv test.apk | grep "\.so"**. 
Alternatively, you can check the **android:extractNativeLibs** value in AndroidManifest.xml of the generated APK file.

Comment: there are two main "build.gradle"s (android and app) which one?

Comment: @temirbek app "build.gradle" (module-level build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

Just Put this code in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

And problem solved all lib that you input in **jnilibs** will be included once your app has been live in PlayStore and installed by the users :)

Comment: Note that although this works, this makes your app bigger for most of your users. You may want to tweak how you load your .so file so that the Android platform finds it. It's not missing, it's just not extracted from the APK at installation time so the platform has to read it from inside the APK directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551499/4265103